# Web-app not available on every 10th call

Tags: apache, jsp, servlets, ubuntu-16.04, tomcat8

I have an odd problem. My Web-app is not available on every 10th call or so, if i click refresh its again available.

If i keep hitting the refresh button, sometimes it shows me again that my Page is not Available. I'm getting HTTP Status 404.

Does anyone know where the problem is ?

Comment: Not without some code to examine.

Comment: There wasn't a error with my Code. 

I deleted the Web-apps from "work/cathalina/localhost" and restarted Tomcat and now everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There wasn't a error with my Code. I deleted the Web-apps from "work/cathalina/localhost" and restarted Tomcat and now everything is working fine.